# How to set unique constraint on nested JSON with multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique-constraint

I'm trying to set a unique constraint between two columns (`name` and `a`), one of type `text`, and one of type `json`. How do I structure this in Postgres 9.6.3?

An example row looks like:

```
{ name: 'someName',
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 'some text'
    }
  }
}
```

What is the postgres command to create a table for this? Currently I have this, which gives a syntax error near `(`.

CREATE TABLE action (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    name text,
    a json,
    unique (name, payload::json#>>'{message, payload, content}')
);

I've also tried

```
CREATE TABLE action (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    name text,
    a json
);
ALTER TABLE actions ADD CONSTRAINT actions_constraint UNIQUE (payload::json#>>'{b, c, d}', name);
```

which keeps giving me this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "::"
```

How can I create this constraint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check documentation [create table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html)

> and table_constraint is:
>
> [CONSTRAINT constraint_name ]
>
> UNIQUE ( column_name [, ... ] ) index_parameters |

`UNIQUE` in `CREATE TABLE` only accepts column names

So if you want index on an expression, you must add it after table created, command for that is [`CREATE INDEX`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createindex.html) (not accomplishable by alter table)

```
create unique INDEX actions_constraint on action (((a#>>'{b, c}')::text), name);
```

> CREATE [ UNIQUE ] INDEX [ CONCURRENTLY ] [ [ IF NOT EXISTS ] name ] ON table_name [ USING method ]
>       ( { column_name | ( expression ) }

Comment: Thanks, what actually worked for me is to remove the `a` from `{a, b, c}`. So the answer is `create unique INDEX actions_constraint on action (((a#>>'{b, c}')::text), name); `. Can you confirm this and change it so I can upvote your answer?